# How to program the same button to do two tasks?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a button called three_button and three_button.setText("Open");

When user clicks button, a frame is opened by the setVisible(true) command.  And the button text changes to Close. Now when I click that button again, I want the frame to be closed this time because the frame is already visible. Code below. I tried creating another handler class within the same handler class, but it didn't work but. Any suggestions?

In other words:

```
if(frame is visible and open) { the button once pressed should close the frame} 

else if (frame is not opened) {the button once pressed should open the frame}
```

Here is my code:

```
thehandler handler = new thehandler();
three_button.addActionListener(handler);

private class thehandler implements ActionListener{ public void
actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

TabbedPaneExample frame = new TabbedPaneExample();
frame.setVisible(true);

three_button.setText("Close"); }}
```

Comment: I suggest that you don't pop JFrames open and closed like this, which can get quite annoying. Do something a little more professional such as swapping views with a CardLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html). Here's a generic example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Test extends JFrame{

    Action actOne = new AbstractAction("One"){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setAction(actTwo);
        }
    };

    Action actTwo = new AbstractAction("Two"){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setAction(actThree);
        }
    };

    Action actThree = new AbstractAction("Three"){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setAction(actOne);
        }
    };

    public Test(){
        super("Test");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JButton(actOne), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(160,120);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        new Test().show();
    }
}
```

Basically when you associate an `Action` with a button, that includes the caption, code to be executed, and possibly mnemonics and accelerators. In any case, it's pretty easy to switch them afterwards.

Comment: I need to make the font of "One" and "Two" bigger. I tried doing actOne.setFont(font) command, but it does not works.

Comment: You can set the font on a `JButton`. E.g. something like `myJButton.setFont(myJButton.getFont().deriveFont(32.0f));`

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a variable that contains the state of the window.

A switch case to increment the state of that variable and in the switch you can apply your logic? And if it has reached its max you can set it to 1

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if(three_botton.getText().equals("Close"))
{
   //do close action
}

else if(three_botton.getText().equals("Open"))
{
   //do open action
}
else if(three_botton.getText().equals("Other"))
{
   //do other action
}
```

Comment: `if (stringVar == "Close")`  You're really recommending to use == to check for String equality? -1.

Comment: I meant:
if(frame is visible and open) { the button once pressed should close the frame}


else if (frame is not opened) {the button once pressed will open the frame}

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I'd think someone with your amount of Rep could edit the post for something as trivial as String comparison. Or at least base your vote in context of the question. Is it wrong to use the button text to determine context-sensitivebehavior?

Comment: hah, yeah sorry, been writing php all day... absolutely .equals.. thanks for the edit...

Comment: also, not saying this is at all the way to do it... just seems like checking state associated with the button is relatively trivial, and basing action on state can be done one of many ways...

Comment: @TimBender, I disagree, the down vote is appropriate. Promoting bad habbits will always get a down vote from me. .